# trouble with responsive website and height

Tags: jquery, html, height, width, adjustment

When you open my website its responsive (not done).
when resizing from the width everything is working right.
but when starting to move the height everything starts looking wrong.
its becouse ive set height 100% on the divs.

When looking on a mobile you see the adressbar on the top. Lets say it is 10% in height my website height will be 90%. But when i scroll down and the bar dissapears the height auto adjusts. Is there a fix?

Im not very goos at this yet. 
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to change some structural stuff. You are having problem with your float elements (texts inside each section) and also with height=100% elements (remove float properties and height=100% of every element and you'll see that you won't have the issue when you resize the viewport's height).
I suggest you to rethink the way you make the structure of your website.
Height=100% elements are a bit tricky. Try to learn what is the natural behavior of a float element so that you'll understand why are you having this issue.
I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%`. Adjust the other containers' heights accordingly to min-heights.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read one more time about RWD layouting. You have some basic errors there (like every rookie, I have made them also in the past). For example you defined #Contact to be 100% height but form inside of it you make always 500px height. That makes some glitches - for example imagine you open this on device which have only 300px in height - your div will get 300px but you said that form need to be at least 500 so it will be higher than its parent. That mean if you using % or ems or other relative unit to a parent you also should make it for its children's.

I also have found in your CSS on line 558 something that breaks your code:

Comment it and test if works correctly.

```
header nav {
   width: 450px;
}
```

It brakes manu content at some point in width terms.

Also I have found you overusing id which makes very hard to make any changes to the site. Basically every div with your background should have same class where you define min-height, margins and other CSS properties which are common to those divs. I advise you to read [this](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php) article. Basicly your CSS for DIVS could look like this:

```
div.section_container {
    min-width:100%;    
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Now if you need to change dimensions of your section divs you just need to change it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Ive already fixed this problem.
I have worked with media query to fix it.

Example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 422px) and (max-width: 466px) {  /*done*/
#About {
    height: 400px;
}

#Portfolio {
    height: 300px;
}
```

}

Im doing this becouse there may be other people searching on google and have the same problem.

Thanks though!